# Frieze groups, wallpaper groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, symmetry

Can someone suggest a source that proves the classifications of the 7 frieze groups and 17 wallpaper groups in an elegant way?

Answer (score 6):

I like The Symmetries of Things by John H. Conway, Heidi Burgiel, and Chaim Goodman-Strauss.

Comment: I was going to put that - it is an extraordinary book with some fantastic diagrams and examples in the elementary bit.

Answer (score 3):

I like these notes on [groups and symmetry](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~ajb/dvi-ps/2q-notes.pdf) by Andrew Baker.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a text by Patrick J. Morandi "[The Classification of Wallpaper Patterns:
From Group Cohomology to Escher's Tessellations](http://sierra.nmsu.edu/Morandi/notes/Wallpaper.pdf)".

He shows that the classification problem leads to the extension problem for groups, which (in this case) can be quite naturally solved using group cohomology. (This makes the classification of wallpaper groups probably the most "down-to-earth" application of homological algebra I have seen so far.)

Although it deals with wallpaper groups only, the same methods can be quite straightforwardly apllied to frieze groups as well (I believe this approach should be able to do the classification quite quickly, i.e. on one or two pages).